# Detect if being run from a USB drive

Tags: c++

Is there any way in C++ to detect if my program is being ran from a thumbdrive? Doing this for issues with USN journals.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try obtaining information about where's your binary located using `fstat(2)` on `argv[0]`.

It's not C++ specific, it works in plain C as well.

After that you may want to enumerate USB devices connected to the system, this operation is OS-dependent (for Linux, e.g., the answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24722076/check-if-certain-usb-flash-memory-is-connected-to-my-system)).

Answer (score 0):

Using the [SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff551967(v=vs.85).aspx) function you get what you want to know.

This may be also interesting for you: [GetDriveType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939(v=vs.85).aspx) function documented on Microsoft developer resources.

The current drive letter you get from `argv [0]`.